# Modem is connected, but no internet in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, internet, connection, usb-modem, modem

Really desperate here.

I have replaced my Linux Mint with Ubuntu 17.04 earlier today. The only way to connect to the internet for me is to use my HSPA modem. I used the default connection options to connect to the internet with the correct APN and other settings. And it connects!

But the problem is, I can't access internet. In Firefox, it keeps spinning and spinning. I can recall, I had connected using the same way a month earlier and it worked perfectly. And even today, while trying, I suddenly got access but it was temporary. I tried using sakis3g, it connects, but I can't access internet.

I can ping both `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` successfully. How can I fix this?

Comment: Change the DNS server to Google's.

Comment: I tried it! Doesn't work.

Comment: Which server address have you used exactly? And such informations, as well, as any other relevant information requested or not are to be added to the question by clicking "edit" below the question or in this one [edit].

Comment: I have the same issue on Lubuntu 17.04. Everything worked fine on Ubuntu 16.04.